# In quantum cryptography, why can a qubit can be both 0 and 1 at the same?

Tags: quantum-cryptography, quantum-key-distribution

The texts below are from some tutorial, and it says (in bold format below) a qubit can be both 0 and 1 at the same time. It sounds very strange to me, can you please explain why?

> Quantum cryptography utilises the physics of photons (light energy
> according to the formula E = hf) and their physical quantum properties to
> produce a virtually unbreakable encryption system. This helps protect the
> security of data being transmitted over fibre optic cables.
> Photons oscillate in various directions and produce a sequence of random
> bits (0s and 1s) across the optical network.
> Sending encryption keys across a network uses quantum cryptography – a
> quantum key distribution (QKD) protocol (one of the most common is
> BB84).
> QKD uses quantum mechanics to facilitate the secure transmission of
> encryption keys. Quantum mechanics use a qubit (quantum bit) as the
> basic unit of quantum data. Unlike normal binary (which uses discrete 0s
> and 1s), the state of a qubit can be 0 or 1, but **it can also be both 0 and 1
> simultaneously**. Figure 17.5 shows a representation of a photon and how a
> photon can be affected by one of four types of polarising filter.

Plus, if some of you ever learned A-level computer science, can you please give some recommendation for A-level computer science books, and exercises?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be mostly a (quantum) physics question (though I'm not stating it's off-topic). IMHO, _"the state of a qubit can be 0 or 1, but it can also be both 0 and 1 simultaneously"_ is a poorly worded approximation. What's 0 and 1 in the first place when referring to the state a qubit? Also, I fear it can't be simply and accurately explained what that sentence is trying to say, much less _"why"_ that is, as asked: in physics, at the lower level (and we are close to it), things are as they are, without the possibility of explaining _why_. It's hard enough to deal with _what_ and _how_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is basic quantum computing that fits [quantum computing.se](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: [Wikibooks: Quantum Key Exchange](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Quantum_Cryptography) and [Wikipedia: Quantum key distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution) might have a slightly easier-to-understand description of the BB84 protocol.

Comment: @kelalaka But QKD is entirely on point here...

Answer (score 10):

“Both 0 and 1 simultaneously” is a [lie-to-children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children): it's a simplification intended to be comprehensible and not fully accurate. It's not a very good one. A better way to present it is that a qubit is partly 0 and partly 1. It's not a single number, it's a function that takes values between 0 and 1.

As for *why*… it's physics. Classical physics says that a particle is in a specific location at a specific time. That works very well when you want to calculate the trajectory of a planet in a solar system. It doesn't work when you want to calculate the trajectory of a subatomic particle. It turns out that a better model of physics is that a particle has a presence density: it's all over the universe, but almost all of it is concentrated in a tiny zone. Similarly, a photon's polarization is not just a direction, but a density (which is more or less the same as a probability distribution): there's a certain proportion of it in every direction. And this is still a lie-to-children — more accurately, the density is a complex number.

Obtaining results from a quantum computer involves summing the density functions of many qubits. It's kind of like adding $n$ numbers between $0$ and $1$ and getting a conclusive result if the sum is either close to $0$ or close to $n$, except with more complex math.

Recommended reading: [“The talk”](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3) by [Scott Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/) and [Zach Weinersmith](https://www.smbc-comics.com/)

Comment: It's not "values between 0 and 1"; the essence of "quantum" is that states are discrete. Rather, it _partly has_ each of the discrete values.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Yes, it's a function (which takes different values at different points) and not just one number. The values aren't between 0 and 1, indeed, that's another lie-to-children — they're complex numbers.

Comment: I did not knew "[The talk](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3)". It's a MUST.